# Create a specific menu right click on a html select option

Tags: jquery, html, select, right-click

I would need to create a html select where, if a option is selected clicking the right button, a new popup is shown with some options. It is important the options aren't hidden when the user clicks on the right button (so I can't use onchange or onclick).

I have tried also to use onclick on the options but doesn't work on Chrome.

Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: do your homework :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495626/making-custom-right-click-context-menus-for-my-web-app... and many-many more solutions can be found on the net...

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to modified the plugin a little bit. Honestly I searched on the Internet but I couldn't find anything useful... And I didn't come across this post

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `oncontextmenu`?
Assuming `element` is the element that will be right clicked:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("rightclicked").style.display = "none";
})
document.body.addEventListener('contextmenu', function() {
  document.getElementById("rightclicked").style.display = "none";
})
document.getElementById("element").addEventListener('contextmenu', function(ev) {
  ev.stopPropagation();
  ev.preventDefault();
  rightclick();
  return false;
}, false);

function rightclick() {
  var e = window.event;
  var cantThinkOfAName = document.getElementById("rightclicked");
  cantThinkOfAName.style.display = "block";
  cantThinkOfAName.style.left = e.clientX + "px";
  cantThinkOfAName.style.top = e.clientY + "px";
}
```

```html
<div id="element">right click</div>
<div id="rightclicked" style="background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);z-index: 100000; width:150px;height: auto; position: absolute; display: none;">
  <ul style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: center; list-style-type: none; text-indent: 0px">
    <a href="#">
      <li style="border-top: none; margin-top: -1px">
        <p>Item1</p>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li>
        <p>Item2</p>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li>
        <p>Item3</p>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li style="margin-bottom: 1px;">
        <p>Item4</p>
      </li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It is a bit more complex on a select tag as when you click it, all elements are compressed. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @user1516059 for that you would set the context menu position property to `position:absolute;` that way it won't affect the layout when shown

Comment: @user1516059 I have provided a complete context menu above, just change some css if you want