# how to show edit button upon right click on table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible that i can show edit button after right clicking on row of a table? I wanted to inbuilt this functionality in my html page but i am not getting the idea how to do that. MY html page is like this

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="tblData">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Parameter Names</th>
            <th>Parameter Values</th>
            <th>Remarks</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td>johnrambo@mail.com</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Rambo</td>
            <td>

                <a class="btn btn-mini btnEdit">Edit</a>
            </td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
        <td>Peter</td>
        <td>Parker</td>
        <td>         

             <a class="btn btn-mini btnEdit">Edit</a>

        </td>

      </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

When i right click on the row of this table then it should show me edit buttin which i can use to edit the table. TO edit the table i have js file but that is other thing. Main thing I want to make the edit button visible after right click.And also I have use bootstrap to improve the visibility. Please help me to solve this problem.[image]

Comment: Check this plugin - https://github.com/sydcanem/bootstrap-contextmenu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code might help you:

## on right clicking on specific `<tr>`

1) no default browser menu opens

2) Show/hide edit link

## On clicking on document (both left and right)

1) hide edit link (can be changed accordingly)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
.btnEdit{display:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>    
      <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="tblData">
        <thead>
          <tr class ='abc'  >
            <th>Parameter Names</th>
            <th>Parameter Values</th>
            <th>Remarks</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr id = 'John1' class ='abc'> <!-- id=username+userid -->
             <td>johnrambo@mail.com</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Rambo</td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-mini btnEdit" href='asd.html' >Edit</a>
            </td>

          </tr>
          <tr id = 'Peter1' class ='abc'>
        <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
        <td>Peter</td>
        <td>Parker</td>
        <td>  
            <a class="btn btn-mini btnEdit" id ="btnEdit" href='asd.html' >Edit</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
</body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $('.abc').contextmenu(function(){
    $('.btnEdit').hide();
    var id  = $(this).attr('id');
      $('#'+id+' .btnEdit').toggle();
      return false;
  });
  $(document).click(function(){
      $('.btnEdit').hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

try it here http://jsfiddle.net/f5n9f4po/2/

Comment: I also wanted multiple edit. I am not able to do so. Can you suggest how to do that?

Comment: means you want to Select multiple users at once and then want to edit records of all users..?

Comment: yes. Basically i want that if i am editing one row then it should be possible for me to edit another row by clicking on edit button.

Comment: yes you can edit multiple records too.
and you are always welcome

Answer (score 1):

The event you're looking to capture is `window.oncontextmenu`. I'm pretty sure you can tie the event to right click by binding it to the `tr` tags.

```
(tr selector).oncontextmenu = function () { 
    toggleEditButton() // callback fn for showing your edit button

    return false; // Prevents actual right click menu from showing up
};
```

Refer to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.oncontextmenu) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it using *onmousedown* event. When you press the mouse button this event will be fired and by checking it's *keyCode* you can find if it's the right mouse button.

*This should serve your purpose.*

**HTML :**

```
<div onmousedown="showEditButton(event);">Row Content</div>
<button id="editButton" style="display:none;">Edit</button>
```

**javaScript :**

```
function showEditButton(event){
    event = event || window.event;
    if(event.which == 3){
        var button = document.getElementById("editButton");
        button.style.display = 'block';        
    }
}
```

[***jsFiddle - javaScript***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/6j8k9agm/)

**jQuery :**

```
$("#editableContent").mousedown(function(event){
    if(event.which == 3){
        $("#editButton").show();
    }
});
```

[***jsFiddle - jQuery***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/swcw1jp9/)

***Resources :***

[***onmousedown***](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousedown.asp) **,** [***.mouseDown()***](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) **,** [***event.which***](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)

Comment: I don't understand why you have writen  event.which == 3. and how it is related to edit button

Comment: using event.which we can get the pressed key's keyCode which is for right mouse button 3. And when found a pressed key having keyCode 3  just displayed the edit button.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on [Making custom right-click context menus for my web-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495626/making-custom-right-click-context-menus-for-my-web-app) implemented to work for your situation.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2kJq/276/)

Here's the JQuery:

```
// Trigger action when the contexmenu is about to be shown
$('.btnEdit').bind("contextmenu", function (event) {

    // Avoid the real one
    event.preventDefault();

    // Show contextmenu
    $(".custom-menu").finish().toggle(100).

    // In the right position (the mouse)
    css({
        top: event.pageY + "px",
        left: event.pageX + "px"
    });
});


// If the document is clicked somewhere
$(document).bind("mousedown", function (e) {

    // If the clicked element is not the menu
    if (!$(e.target).parents(".custom-menu").length > 0) {

        // Hide it
        $(".custom-menu").hide();
    }
});


// If the menu element is clicked
$(".custom-menu li").click(function () {

    // This is the triggered action name
    switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {

        // A case for each action. Your actions here
        case "edit":
            alert("Edited!");
            break;
    }

    // Hide it AFTER the action was triggered
    $(".custom-menu").hide();
});
```