# Open an extension popup (html list) on right click of node (contextmenu) in visjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, treeview

I want to open a extension popup on right click of node in visjs. I tried many things but none seem to be helpful. I want popup to be an ordered list

Comment: It doesn't look like vis.js has a feature for a context menu. There is an open feature request, but this doesn't look like a vis.js specific feature. Are you just wanting a context menu?

Comment: Yes. I want a context menu. On click of a node I can display a list of all attributes.

Comment: @mwilson Also one more help needed. Inside a node I want to have an image as well as label. Can it be happen for visjs ?   I can either have an image or label inside a node. Currently If I have an image then label is coming outside of the node

Comment: var nodes = new vis.DataSet([                                                                {id:0, label:'Hello1', image:'../images/Picture1.jpg', shape:'image', title:'Hello1'},                                                                                       {id:0, label:'Hello2', image:'../images/Picture2.jpg', shape:'image', title:'Hello2'}]);

Answer (score 10):

A really good explanation of how to create a context menu can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20471268).

Below is the relevant JS code for vis.js using the linked example.

With your vis.Network var, assuming it's called network:

```
network.on("oncontext", function (params) {

    params.event.preventDefault();
    $(".custom-menu").finish().toggle(100);
    $(".custom-menu").css({
        top: params.event.pageY + "px",
        left: params.event.pageX + "px"
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How could I get details of the node that was right-clicked?

Comment: There is an API for this: `network.getNodeAt(params.poiner.DOM)`

Comment: Sorry for the misprint:
params.poiner.DOM -> params.pointer.DOM