# Right Click Context Menu with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contextmenu

I want to have a contextmenu listening on a right-click on a specific cell.

In html file, I linked the Script by writing

```
<script src="ContextMenuController.js"></script> // link the js file
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ContextMenuStyle.css"> // link the css file
```

In my js-file i want to create this contextmenu by writing

```
$(this).closest('td').onmousedown = function(event) { // get the cell clicked on
    if (event.which == 3) { // just build the menu on a right click

      var contextElements = ["btnAddRowAbove", "btnAddRowBelow", "btnAddColumnLeft",
      "btnAddColumnRight", "btnMoveRowUp", "btnMoveRowDown", "btnMoveColumnLeft",
      "btnMoveColumnRight", "btnDeleteRow", "btnDeleteColumn", "btnUndo", "btnRedo"]; // store all the buttons of the menu

      var menuText = "<ul class=\"contextmenu\">"; // the wrapper
      for (var i = 0; i < contextElements.length; i++) {
        menuText += "<li id= contextElements[i]> contextElements[i] <\/li>"; // append all the buttons to the wrapper
      }
      return menuText + "<\/ul>"; // finish the wrapper
    }};
```

When i try to debug it with `alert()` the code does not even reach this function.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Why don't you use `contextmenu` menu event? Attached it all `td`s and display the menu according to the position of the target.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495626/making-custom-right-click-context-menus-for-my-web-app

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The fiddle helped me a lot. But when i finished the context menu i thought it would be better to have a ribbon. The context menu felt ... annoying... :/