# New element in the context menu of a contenteditable <div>

Tags: javascript, html, contextmenu, contenteditable

**How to add a new element in the context menu of a `contenteditable` `<div>`?**

I'd like to add an option "Show HTML" that would display the raw HTML that is inside the div.

```js
document.getElementById("a").oncontextmenu = function() { 
  alert("How to add a new element in the Context menu?"); 
}
```

```html
<div id="a" contenteditable="true">Hello you, <strong>right-click</strong> here and see the <a href="#">new option</a> <i>"Show HTML"</i></div>
```

Note: Unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909167/how-to-add-a-custom-right-click-menu-to-a-webpage) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495626/making-custom-right-click-context-menus-for-my-web-app) I don't want to override the normal context menu and build a new one, but **add a new element to the existing context menu**:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making custom right-click context menus for my web-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495626/making-custom-right-click-context-menus-for-my-web-app)

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909167/how-to-add-a-custom-right-click-menu-to-a-webpage

Comment: @lilezek I edited the question to explain it, but it's not a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @Intervalia See the end of edited question.

Comment: From what I know and have read the only way to alter the native context menu, as of today, 11/17/2017, is to use the `<menu>` tag and that only works on Firefox. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contextmenu

Answer (score 0):

You can not use this in all browsers. Method  of defining a context menu item, now deprecated and removed from the HTML specification. https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/interactive-elements.html#context-menus,

https://caniuse.com/#search=contextmenu