# Best way to protect video from downloading

Tags: javascript, html, video, piracy-prevention

What is the best way to make it harder for the user to download videos from my website?. I know it is impossible to prevent it at all. But I just want to make it more difficult than just secondary click, save as. I'm rendering as html5 video tag. I'm using  to remove download button from controls. But still can save the video using secondary click and save video as. There is an effective way to make it a little bit difficult to the user from downloading videos from my website?.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756837/prevent-html5-video-from-being-downloaded-right-click-saved

Comment: Even though there is no way to just simply block the save as option. I did find this: [Custom right-click menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495626/making-custom-right-click-context-menus-for-my-web-app/20471268#20471268) This will allow you to sort of disable the save as function.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I already find the answer to my question here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756837/prevent-html5-video-from-being-downloaded-right-click-saved

Answer (score 1):

This question where answered before but I post here the solution that I got from Clayton Graul [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756837/prevent-html5-video-from-being-downloaded-right-click-saved) :)

This is a simple solution for those wishing to simply remove the right-click "save" option from the html5 videos

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#videoElementID').bind('contextmenu',function() { return false; });
});
```

Comment: but if a person check the network logs, he would be able to get the url