# Trying to prevent standard right click menu

Tags: javascript

I am trying to prevent the standard right click menu from popping up on some information so i can display my own custom right click menu.

Right now I am getting both with the standard one appearing over the custom.

Here's my html:

`<span onmouseup=\"OnRowMouseUp('Filename');\">Filename</span>`

Here's my JavaScript:

```
var OnRowMouseUp = function (selectedField) {
    e = window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
    //this.ShowContextMenu(selectedField, e.clientX, e.clientY);
}
```

e is definitely a mouse event as I can view it in console. A lot of the other SO answers say that I should be using `preventDefault()` but it dosen't seem to be working in this circumstance. Any ideas?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault#Blocking_default_click_handling

Comment: Just an idea. There are 3 events: mousedown, click and mouseup. Maybe try experimenting with all 3 of them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making custom right-click context menus for my web-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495626/making-custom-right-click-context-menus-for-my-web-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `contextmenu` event.

```
<span oncontextmenu="OnRowMouseUp(Filename);">Filename</span>
```

Or

```
element.addEventListener('contextmenu', () => {

});
```

After this, preventDefault should work as expected.

Comment: Awesome. If you want you can mark this answer as accepted so people know the question has been taken care of.

Comment: Yeah. 15 minutes after question is asked. Anyway thanks a lot. o7

Comment: Happy to help :)